# Automatically add attributes to woocommerce product?

Tags: plugins, php, actions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to make WooCommerce automatically add some attributes to a product when it's created.

I'm trying to find the right hook to start with, so far the only one that seems correct is 'woocommerce_api_create_product' but it doesn't work and the WooCommerce help site actually goes to a 404 not found page for that hook.

I'm trying to get this code to execute:

```
if ( $new_status == "auto-draft" && isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'product' ){

    // do stuff here
        $defaults = array ( 'pa_color' => array (
                                      'name' => 'pa_color',
                                      'value' => '',
                                      'position' => 1,
                                      'is_visible' => 1,
                                      'is_variation' => 1,
                                      'is_taxonomy' => 1,
                                   ),
                            'pa_capacity' => array (
                                      'name' => 'pa_capacity',
                                      'value' => '',
                                      'position' => 2,
                                      'is_visible' => 1,
                                      'is_variation' => 1,
                                      'is_taxonomy' => 1,
                                   )
        );

    update_post_meta( $post->ID , '_product_attributes', $defaults );

}
```

Comment: Please, show the complete callback. I assume it's post status transition?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'create_product', 10 );
function create_product( $post_id, $post) {   
    // $post_id and $post are required
    if ( empty( $post_id ) || empty( $post ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Dont' save meta boxes for revisions or autosaves
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) || is_int( wp_is_post_revision( $post ) ) || is_int( wp_is_post_autosave( $post ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the nonce
    if ( empty( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'], 'woocommerce_save_data' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the post being saved == the $post_id to prevent triggering this call for other save_post events
    if ( empty( $_POST['post_ID'] ) || $_POST['post_ID'] != $post_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check user has permission to edit
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    //Only if this is a new published product
    if ($post->post_date != $post->post_modified) {
        return;
    }

    // do stuff here...
}
```